Generating Function Calculation

Suzanne went to the bank and withdrew dollar $800$. The teller gave her this
amount using dollar $20$ bills, dollar $50$ bills, and dollar $100$ bills, with at least
one of each denomination. How many different collections of bills
could Suzanne have received? (AMC 2023 10B/11)

Solution 5 uses generating functions to get:
$$(x^{82}-1)(x^{85}-1)(x^{90}-1)(x^2-1)^{-1}(x^5-1)^{-1}(x^{10}-1)^{-1}.$$
but how would you find the coefficient of $x^{80}$ in the above. I get that the first three terms can be ignored.
But am not able to find a way after that which does not bring me back to the Diophantine/Stars and Bars methods used in the other solutions.

First of all, that solution is wrong, because it is not accounting for the constraint that there must be at least one of each denomination. The correct way to implement that idea would be $(x^2-x^{82})/(1-x^2)\cdot (x^5-x^{85})/(1-x^5)\cdot (x^{10}-x^{90})/(1-x^{10})$. Secondly, I think the generating function solution does not provide any insight that was not already present in solutions 1 through 4.

Technically, the generating function allows you to read off its recurrence (if its a rational polynomial). But you still have to compute the initial values and then run the recurrence till the 80th step.  A bit more generally speaking it's a nice representation of the problem which you can easily throw at a CAS to get (or check) the solution.

@Sudix So then not useful in an exam where you have an average of 3 minutes per question......

Duplicate surely.

I we have $\,1\,$ $\,\$100\,$ bill, then there are $\,6\,$ combinations of $\,\$50s\,$ and $\,\$20s\,$ to make up the remaining $\,\$700\,$ where $\,\$50s\,$ are in multiples of $\,2\,$ and $\,\$20s\,$ are in multiples of $\,5.\,$ Examples are $\,5\,$ $\,\$20s\,$ and $\,12\,$ $\,\$50s\,$ or $\,10\,$ $\,\$20s\,$ and $\,10\,$ $\,\$50s.\,$
I we have  $\,2\,$ $\,\$100\,$ bills, then there are $\,5\,$ combinations.
I we have $\,3\,$ $\,\$100\,$ bills, then there are $\,4\,$
combinations.
I we have  $\,4\,$ $\,\$100\,$ bills, then there are $\,3\,$ combinations.
I we have  $\,5,$ $\,\$100\,$ bills, then there are $\,2\,$ combinations.
I we have  $\,6\,$ $\,\$100\,$ bills, then there are $\,1\,$ combinations.
$$\sum_1^6 x=21$$
The final "function" should specify that there are the sum of $\,7-h$ combinations where $\,h\,$ is the number of $\,\$100s\,$ in any given combo.

Question is on generating functions. Could you explain how your answer relates to generating functions.
